# Customizing XML deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, namespaces

So I was using `DataContractSerializer` to save my application's documents to disk. All of the types used by the `Document` class lived in one namespace, like this:

```
namespace MyProjectVM
{
  class Document
  {
    public Apple[] Apples { get; set; }
    public Orange SelectedOrange { get; set; }
  }

  class Apple { ... }
  class Orange { ... }
}
```

My serializer looked like this:

```
private static readonly Type[] AllObjectTypes = {
      typeof(Apple),
      typeof(Orange),
    };

private DataContractSerializer S = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Document), AllObjectTypes, 0x7F_FFFF, false, true, null);
```

All looked good. Things were serializing nicely to the disk and I could deserialize them too.

I then had to do some refactoring. Classes `Apple` and `Orange` were moved to a new project (and therefore a different namespace). This has broken backward compatibility and old documents can no longer be deserialized. I get all sorts of XML namespace-related errors about those migrated classes.

I'm currently trying to fix this problem by intercepting deserialization process, by inheriting from `XmlReader` and returning new project's namespace for `Apples` and `Oranges` nodes, like this:

```
public override string NamespaceURI
{
  get
  {
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
      switch (reader.Name)
      {
        case "Apples":
        case "Oranges":
          return "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NewProject";

        default:
          return reader.NamespaceURI;
      }
    }
    else
      return inner.NamespaceURI;
  }
}
```

but it still doesn't work. Seems like I namespaces work together with prefixes and that's where I have got totally confused. `DataContractSerializer` appears to be generating automated prefixes of the form `d1p3`, `d2p1` etc.

Am I on the correct path or is there a better way of handling this? If this approach is correct, how do I relate prefixes to namespaces?

Comment: Have you try adding  the attribute `[DataContract(Namespace = "yourOldNamespace")]` to the properties to be de/serialize?

Comment: @Nekeniehl: You mean I add this attribute to `Apples` and `Oranges` properties of `Document` class? Mind that these classes no longer exist in the old namespace.

Comment: But you mention that your classes are serialized right now with the old namespace. Even if those doesn't exists anymore in the new namespace, maybe helps forcing to deserialize using your oldnamespace in the new project.

Comment: @Nekeniehl: mmm... the problem is not with the serialization/deserialization of current structure. They are working correctly. Problem is with the deserialization of old documents that were serialized using the previous version of the application, so if put that attribute to my properties, even the new documents will not deserialize, obviously because those class now do not in that old namespace anymore.

Comment: That is what I mean, sorry I am not good at explanations, maybe this links helps you a little -> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/86a210cf-f788-440b-b7fd-a99e79f1ad46/datacontractserializer-serialize-data-between-different-namespaces?forum=wcf